# How to use an image of text as a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the image that I want to get rid of the white stuff

[image]

I will try to make this post better than the last one I made. My only question is, the code I have produces a screen with the background as an image. What I want to do is make the button be an image of text. However, when I make the button the image, there is white space around where the text does not fill the button box. I have made sure to remove any background of the image. I was wondering if there is a way to remove the white bits. Much appreciated.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class HoverButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        tk.Button.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.defaultBackground = self["background"]
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, e):
        self['background'] = self['activebackground']

    def on_leave(self, e):
        self['background'] = self.defaultBackground

def main_screen():

    global main
    main = Tk()
    main.title("Home")
    main.geometry("800x600")

    filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\frase\Documents\\bg.png")
    bg_label = Label(main, image=filename)
    bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    playfile = tk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\frase\Documents\\button.png")

    b = Button(main, text="Play", image = playfile, highlightthickness=0, bd=0)
    b.pack()

    main.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Comment: is the original image .png?

Comment: yes it is a png image

Comment: @2__D: Define `.Button(..., width=182, height=66, ...` **2 pixel** less than your image dimension.

Comment: I have just tried that. My image is 151x67, so in the b = button i added in width and height to be -2 those values, and still the white bits persist

I changed the widget to be:
b = Button(main, text = Play, image = playfile, width = 149, height = 65)